# Reading "Protected view" file data

Tags: php, phpexcel, xls

I'm trying to read .xls file using PHPExcel with createReaderForFile.
When I'm trying to read the file that was originally created, I get "##0#" when reading A1 data (this file is under "protected view" and can not be edited in Excel).

Saving the same file content in a new file, and running the same script on it, returns the required result.

Anything I'm missing here?

(this is the code - just in case)

```
$file = 'summary.xls';
$Reader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReaderForFile($file);
$Reader->setReadDataOnly(true); 
$objXLS = $Reader->load($file);
$value = $objXLS->getSheet(0)->getCellByColumnAndRow(1,2)->getValue(); 
$objXLS->disconnectWorksheets();
unset($objXLS);
echo $value;
```